# How to replace an apostrophe in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Given a string in Javacript, such as

```
var str = "this's kelly";
```

I want to replace the apostrophe (') with another character. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
str.replace('&quot;', 'A');
str.replace('\'', 'A');
```

None of these work.

How do I do it?

Can you also please advices me with the invalid characters  that when passed to the query string or URL crashes the page or produces undesired results ? e.g passing apostrophe (') produces undesired result are their any more of them.

Comment: You already have a working script... `str.replace('\'', 'A'); -- does not work` <-- that actually DOES work.

Comment: a common gotcha - it does not modify the string it's called on, it returns a new one.

Comment: @kinnan-nawaz Re: Invalid characters - that's not really part of your original question. You might want to make a new question so that it will get answered.

Answer (score 39):

```
var str = "this's kelly"
str = str.replace(/'/g, 'A');
```

The reason your version wasn't working is because `str.replace` returns the new string, without updating in place.

I've also updated it to use the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) version of `str.replace`, which when combined with the `g` option replaces all instances, not just the first. If you actually wanted it to just replace the first, either remove the `g` or do `str = str.replace("'", 'A');`

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
str = str.replace("'","A");
```

Answer (score 3):

str = str.replace("'", "A");

Your running the function but not assigning it to anything again so the var remains unchanged