# How to replace an apostrophe in a string in Javascript CORRECTLY?

Tags: javascript

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871289/how-to-replace-an-apostrophe-in-a-string-in-javascript) the highest rated answer is working, but I have 2 problems with it:

- it is diplayed incorrectly in vim (everything is highlighted with red from the first apostrophe until the last semicolon)
- ctags doesn't include the function (which contains that `.replace(/'/g, 'A')`) in the tags file

Is it possible to escape the apostrophes somehow?

Comment: use `.replace(/\'/g, 'A')`

Comment: Those both sound like issues with vim and/or your various plugins for it. (Most likely the plugins; I haven't had any trouble with vim not understanding incredibly basic JavaScript syntax, and I've used it for JavaScript **a lot**.) The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11871312/157247) to the question you linked absolutely does it "CORRECTLY".

Comment: @Reyno there's no need to escape `'` characters in a JavaScript regular expression.

Comment: @Pointy i know, but he asked if it was possible to escape the apostophe

Comment: escaping that apostrophe I have the same result: it is working but the same issues in vim/ctags

Comment: Generally text editors "cheat" in parsing in order to do syntax highlighting, and sometimes they simply don't work. It's not a problem with the source code.

Comment: so no other way to reformat that .replace() in order to work in vim/ctags? And the problem is that not only that function is not tagged, but every other that comes after in that file... :(

Comment: Please, report the problem of ctags as an issue to https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues .